# Show That the Linear Transformation is NOT linear

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm presently reviewing my teachers optional notes and I cannot seem to understand how I can show that the following transformation is NOT linear. I don't need a complex proof, just a short explanation. Thanks :)

$$T([x_1,x_2]) = [x_1 - 2x_2, x_1 - 3, 2x_1 - 5x_2]$$

Comment: Look at $T(x + y)$ and compare it with $T(x)$ + $T(y)$. Note that the $-3$ term will give you some trouble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**

If $T$ is linear then
$$T([0,0])=[0,0,0]$$

Answer (score 6):

Showing something is not linear merely requires a counterexample. And typically, if something isn't linear, then nearly any example you consider will be a counter-example unless you have a systematic bias in your choices.

So really, all you have to do is the following, without requiring any creativity or cleverness in your choices:

- Pick a vector $v$
- Pick a vector $w$
- Compute $T(v) + T(w)$
- Compute $T(v+w)$
- If they are equal, go back to step 1
- Otherwise, you're done.

Alternatively

- Pick a vector $v$
- Pick a scalar $r$
- Compute $T(rv)$
- Compute $rT(v)$
- If they are equal, go back to step 1
- Otherwise, you're done.

Comment: In terms of answering a homework question, the accepted answer is great. But for understanding the concept, your answer is a million times better than the accepted one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider $T([0,0])$. You have $T([0,0])=[0,-3,0]$, so $T([0,0])+T([0,0])=[0,-6,0] \neq T([0,0]+[0,0])=T([0,0])$, but for linear transformation if $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$.